# "cannot set terminal process group" error when running bash script

Tags: shell-command, bash

I have the following two lines of code in my init.el file:

```
(setq shell-file-name "bash")
(setq shell-command-switch "-ic")
```

I tried executing the following script to get a list of executables using the shell script dmenu_path.

```
(defun dmenu-path-out ()
  (shell-command-to-string "dmenu_path"))
```

I see the following error:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
[
0ad
...
```

How can I prevent bash from returning that error when using `shell-command`?

Comment: Possibly partial duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670209/cygwin-bash-does-not-display-correctly-in-emacs-shell/52643961#52643961 there seems to be no solution yet if your shell is cygwin's bash

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `-i` flag requests that Bash run in interactive mode, which requires a terminal.  The solution is to leave the `shell-command-switch` variable at its default value, which is just `-c`.

If you really need to run Bash in interactive mode, you will need to run it in a pseudo-terminal, by using `start-file-process` with `process-connection-type` bound to `t`.

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: It works for me. As an example, this command launches `gnome-terminal`, runs `echo` and leaves the Bash session running and ready to take new commands: `(start-file-process-shell-command "peekaboo" "*Messages*" "gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'echo Peekaboo!; bash'")`; any output from the Elisp command is sent to the `*Messages*` buffer. Note that I used `start-file-process-shell-command` instead of `start-file-process`, so I don't need to give the path to shell programs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `-i` to get bash to expand aliases?  If so, as given in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224909, instead include

```
(setenv "BASH_ENV" "~/.bashrc")
```

in your .emacs and

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

in your .bashrc.  The former causes your .bashrc to be run on your sub-shells, and the latter allows alias expansion in non-login bash shells.

You can go one better by creating a separate shell script with your aliases and the shopt line, and using that as the BASH_ENV value; that may run faster than your full ~/.bashrc.

Comment: Can you please summarize the fix detailed there? Otherwise this is essentially a link-only answer and so risks being deleted.