# How to get the PATH from the SHELL

Tags: shell, emacsclient, linux, bash, environment

When launched at system start-up, the Emacs daemon doesn't pick up modifications to the `PATH` introduced by shell initialization scripts.

[Emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ExecPath) suggests to use this function to update Emacs' PATH,

```lisp
(defun set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH ()
  "Set up Emacs' `exec-path' and PATH environment variable to match
that used by the user's shell.

This is particularly useful under Mac OS X and macOS, where GUI
apps are not started from a shell."
  (interactive)
  (let ((path-from-shell (replace-regexp-in-string
              "[ \t\n]*$" "" (shell-command-to-string
                      "$SHELL --login -i -c 'echo $PATH'"
                            ))))
    (setenv "PATH" path-from-shell)
    (setq exec-path (split-string path-from-shell path-separator))))

(set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH)
```

but it returns some errors:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

As far as I understand ([my main reference](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/cannot-set-terminal-process-group-error-when-running-bash-script)), since I want to run Bash in interactive mode (so that it loads `~/.bashrc`) I should use `start-file-process`(`-shell-command`) to invoke the shell process. However, I can't figure out how to store the output of the command in a string when I do so.

Comment: I fixed the doc in the [Emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ExecPath) and opened an issue on the [source of the misinformation](https://github.com/Wilfred/ag.el/issues/172),

Comment: Good Q and A. Thanks for fixing that wiki page, @NickD

Comment: There is the package exec-path-from-shell - also see Aquamacs code for another way

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you don’t want to use `-i` because you’re not launching an interactive shell. That is, this shell will not be connected to a terminal that the user can type in. It is instead going to be connected to a pipe so that Emacs can read whatever it prints. Removing the `-i` option will prevent Bash from trying to use inappropriate ioctls on the stdout and stdin, and thus eliminate the error messages.

If your `PATH` is only configured by your `~/.bashrc` file, then you’ve misconfigured Bash. You should ensure that at least your `PATH` is set up consistently in both interactive and non—interactive shells. Most distros do this by making the default `~/.bash_profile` source `~/.bashrc` for you. Configuring this correctly will ensure that you get the correct `PATH` value.

Comment: how do I configure this correctly?

Comment: Configure it correcty by setting PATH in `~/.bash_profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`. That way your PATH variable is correctly set in both interactive and non–interactive shells.